# Disable iPhone numeric keyboard auto-toggle

Tags: ios, keyboard, iphone

When using the iOS keyboard and inserting an apostrophe or a space the keyboard automatically toggles from the numeric screen back to the qwerty input screen. I'm finding this really annoying, so how do I turn this 'feature' off?

E.g. When typing in a UK postcode or commenting numbers in a spreadsheet cell

Comment: Do you have your keyboard set to English UK? You can check this in Settings > General > Keyboards

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with iOS 7 and iOS 8. Sadly I don't have any experience with iOS 6 or lower.

Ok I might have found a solution:

IOS 7, 8 AND 9 beta 1 and 2:

1) Go to settings, then keyboards

2) Uncheck ALL the options on that page.

3) Test it (in the app where it's affecting you)

OR:

Just uncheck split keyboard and see if that works.

Comment: Not an option. Not going to disable half the functionality for the occasional postcode.

Comment: Added a new line. Try to see if it fixes it by us checking split keyboard

Comment: I don't have an option for split keyboard, that's iPad only.

Comment: Your 1st solution doesn't work on 7.1.2 :(.

Comment: Should we expect it to?